# Scala not builds on Java 10

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, build.gradle, java-10

while building through Intellij Idea, I got the following message:

> Error:scalac: 'jvm-1.10' is not a valid choice for '-target'
>   Error:scalac: bad option: '-target:jvm-1.10'

later, after a Java upgrade

> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Gradle JVM:
>   1.8 Build, Execution, Deployment -> Complier -> Scala Complier -> Scala Compile Server -> JDK: 1.8

in `build.gradle`

```
compileScala.targetCompatibility = 1.8
ScalaCompileOptions.metaClass.useAnt = false
```

Nothing helps!

**upd:**
this helps: in `build.gradle`

```
tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) {
    scalaCompileOptions.useAnt = false
}
```

not needed:

```
compileScala.targetCompatibility = 1.8 
ScalaCompileOptions.metaClass.useAnt = false
```

Comment: which Scala version are you using? Please check [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html)

Comment: my scala version is 2.12.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Error:scalac: 'jvm-1.10' is not a valid choice for '-target' Error:scalac: bad option: '-target:jvm-1.10'"

- In the **JDK compatibility notes** as mentioned below, it also **indicates
  that the Java 10 is not fully supporting Scala  2.12.6**  [JDK 9 & 10
  compatibility notes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html)
- As you were saying you build this through IntelliJ IDEA, I suspect
  you haven't configure your java version (Java 10) or scala version
  (2.12.6) inside running configuration project settings.
- And also please try out building/compile your application through
  commandline in order to check whether you are getting the same error 
  with that (Otherwise this is just bad configuration in IDEA tht you
  need to change)

### JDK 9 & 10 compatibility notes (Mentioned in Scala Docs)

JDK 9 & 10 compatibility notes
As of Scala 2.12.6 and 2.11.12, JDK 9 & 10 support is incomplete. Notably, scalac will not enforce the restrictions of the Java Platform Module System, which means that code that typechecks may incur linkage errors at runtime.

JDK 9 & 10 support requires minimum sbt version 1.1.0, or 0.13.17 in the 0.13.x series.

For more information on JDK 9 & 10 compatibility, watch the “Support JDK 9” issue on GitHub.

Comment: This Intellj IDEA configuration issue. Thanks!

Comment: @HoTicE Great :) Most of the time IntelliJIDEA is not properly set with the intended configurations, it's better to rely on the command line output :)

Answer (score 2):

The same issue can happen with mixed multi-module gradle projects that use java 11 and scala 2.12.10.

In that case, it may help to reconfigure IntelliJ (2019.2) via

`Settings` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Scala Compiler`

by **removing the targets defined in `Additional compiler options`** for the affected scala modules.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled over this issue when having the same problem with Java 11. The reconfiguration comment of Roland Ewald solved the problem. It is important to mention, that this reconfiguration has to be made for all modules of the project (at least for me this was necessary) as well as that IntelliJ sometimes hides parts of the `Additional compiler options`, so be sure to click on expand even if they *seem* empty or correct.